# Reportviewer - Make consecutive repeating rows become one

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, report-viewer2010

may I know how to do with the scenario describe below?

Lets say I have a dataset with 4 columns, and I have 3 consecutive repeating criteria of `Date`, `Name` and `ID` but not quantity. How can i make it become one row that sums all the 3 rows before? How can I do this in report viewer?

```
Date      Name          ID          Quantity
____________________________________________
21/3     John           001         10
         John           001         20
         John           001         10
```

And I want to make it like:

```
Date      Name          ID          Quantity
____________________________________________
21/3     John           001         40
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Agustin, how do you did that?

Comment: Oh ya, is sql query able to achieve this? Select distinct, group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using GROUP BY query.
For instance:

```
SELECT Date, Name, ID, SUM(Quantity) as Quantity
From EmpTable
GROUP BY Date, Name, ID
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Simple though, I just thought that report viewer can do this.
Thanks